# Rotational Constant and Moment of Inertia of Fluorine gas

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I have come across some homework question on thermodynamics which needs me to calculate $B$ of $F_2$

My attempt:

$B= \frac{h}{8\pi^2cI}$ where $I=\mu r^2=\frac{m_1m_2}{m_1+m_2} r^2$

Atomic mass of fluorine atom is $18.998$ $g$ ${mol}^{-1}$ and Bond length is $141.8\times10^{-12}$

$B=\frac{6.626\times 10^{-34}}{8 \pi^2 (3\times10^{10})\frac{\frac{18.998^2}{18.998\times2}}{6.02\times 10^{23} \times 1000}(141.8\times10^{-12})^2}\approx0.882$

which I think it is wrong because when I continue to calculate the rotational temperature $\Theta_R$, the result is way too low.

$\Theta_R=\frac{hcB}{k_B}=\frac{(6.63\times10^-34)(3\times10^{10})(0.882)}{1.38\times10^{-23}}=1.27 K$, $K$ for kelvin.

Please help me find the mistakes in the calculations...

Comment: as far as I can tell everything you have written is in meters-kilograms-seconds (SI) units, EXCEPT for the speed of light which you have written in centimeters/seconds.

Comment: Actually, I don't think it matters because it should cancel in $\Theta_R$, BUT your mass is given in grams and not Kg. You need to double check all of your units here.

Comment: @sujeet yes, Ive checked and I think my units have been used correct. Thats why I want to see anyone here can point out which unit did I use is wrong. Because a lot of variable in thermodynamics dont use SI units.

Comment: @sujeet I think we need to use $Kg$ as the unit of reduced mass here..

Comment: Paul, are you sure it's wrong? Rotational temperature for $\mathrm{CO}_2$ is $\sim0.5\,\mathrm{K}$ according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotational_temperature

Comment: @sujeet Im not sure, because there is a follow up question which asks us to plot probability of $p_j$ in different level $j$ in low/intermediate/high temperature. The equation Im using is just for intermediate temperature which suits most case. If the number is really that small what is the low temperature? $0$ $K$, the equation will blow up.

Comment: Paul, this is beyond my depth in this subject, but the way to get temperatures much smaller than $1\,\mathrm{K}$ would be numbers like $10^{-10}\,\mathrm{K}$.